# Class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' not found error in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

While loading the dynamic page in laravel 5.2 I am getting below error.

> FatalThrowableError in ConnectionFactory.php line 217:
>   Class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' not found

what might be the issue.how to solve these I have tried below commands none of these helped to rectify the above issue.

1. composer dump-autoload
2. php artisan cache:clear
3. php artisan route:cache
4. php artisan config:cache

Answer (score 14):

For me deleting the vendor directory and re-running composer install fixed this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a `sudo rm -R vendor` in your projects directory followed by a `composer install` and everything should work.

Comment: Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

I am not using Laravel 5.2 but 5.7.28 instead. I followed @jgleesti's solution deleting the vendor folder and re-running composer install. It made it better but didn't solve my problem. So I did some more steps to solve my issue.

> sudo apt-get --purge remove php-common
>
> sudo apt-get install php-common php-mysql php-cli php-bcmath

Not sure how, but it works for me.

Comment: I used this method and got rid of the error. However I also needed to re-install php-fpm.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps solved this error for me. My composer version was ^1 and I upgrade it to composer version ^2.

1. Removed vendor using command `sudo rm -rf vendor`
2. Checked composer version `sudo composer --version`
3. Uninstalled composer `sudo apt-get remove composer -y`
4. `php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`
5. `sudo php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`
6. `php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer`
7. `composer self-update --2`
8. `composer install`

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same issue, it seems the PDO is not working on my site,

1. Tried to purge the PHP / MySQL
2. Reinstall PHP / MySQL

It seems that the module for pdo loaded from PHP – ini and PHP – m

Comment: I freshly download the laravel framework and migrated all the files from old project now it's fine